# How to mount USB to Linux Docker Container from Windows Host

Tags: docker, usb

I've set up a Docker container running Linux from my Windows Host. Now I need to use a USB2CAN Dongle in my Docker container. How do I mount the USB device to the Docker container?

Thanks in advance!